# Action link is not working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, actionlink

I have created a view in View>Shared folder

Which has this code

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account", new { data_role = "button" })</text>
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account", new { data_role = "button" })

}
```

Than I have created a controller in the controller folder

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

and by right click on the Index logOn and LogOff views are created in the folder 
Views> Account

But when I am clicking on the Log On button I am not redirecting to the logOn page.

**Please help**

Comment: What URL are you expecting, what URL are you getting? Does your controller `[Authorize]` attribute? This question needs more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a route for this? Also type in the expected URL and see if you can get to it. Does it show the right url when you mouse over the link?

Comment: I didn't change anything else. All is default

Comment: What he's saying is to make sure your logon page works by navigating to it directly. If it does work, then you need to look at the html for button to see if the url is formed correctly.

Comment: @rboarman thanks for explanation, when I am running this http://localhost:14518/Account/LogOn I can see my page

Comment: ok.. and when you mouse over the link for logon, what url does it show you?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the link, what URL does it give you? It may be that you are resolving to the wrong overload of ActionLink. I've had this happen before as well. Add an extra null parameter in your ActionLink call and it should resolve to the correct one.